# PHP Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed Error

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error

PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed

My code is below

```
   <?php
   $pdfLink = 
   $backendCGI.'/'.$_REQUEST['link'].'?'.$_REQUEST['arguments'].'&sessionID='.session_id();
   $lines_array=file($pdfLink);
   $lines_string=implode('',$lines_array);
   header('Content-type: application/pdf');  
   ob_flush();
   flush();
   echo $lines_string;  
?>
```

Comment: `$lines_array` is an array? What's in `var_dump($lines_array);` ?

Comment: `file()` returns `FALSE` on error, thats in invalid argument for `implode`. You should check the content off `$lines_array` before using it. Consider `is_array` or `empty()`

Comment: You are trying to implode an array. Either use `file_get_contents()` instead of `file()` or use `str_split()` instead of implode. Use `var_dump()` when in doubt

Comment: @NVRM not sure about `str_split()` but totally agree that `file_get_contents()` would be much better here